# Configuring a filter within a WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: spring-security

I've been having all sorts of giggles configuring some custom filters in the spring security filter chain.  The primary problem surrounds a custom AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.  This filter requires the AuthenticationManager as well as the SessionAuthenticationStrategy.  Using the adapter:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
....

AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter processingFilter = new MyAuthenticationProcessingFilter();

processingFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
processingFilter.setSessionAuthenticationStrategy(http.getSharedObject(SessionFixationProtectionStrategy.class));
http.addFilterBefore(processingFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

First, I had problems with the authenticationManager() returning null.  Tracing that down showed that during the creation/initialization of the adapter and specifically the WebSecurity.init() method invoking getHttp(), this code ultimately calls AuthenticationManagerBuilder.build() which returns null at performBuild()

```
if(!isConfigured()) {
   logger.debug("No authenticationProviders and no parentAuthenticationManager defined. Returning null.");
   return null;
}
```

Sadly, this then flags the AuthenticationManager as initialized (to null) and forever returns the wrong result.. all this before it even gets to my adapter code!  I finally figured out I could use authenticationManagerBean() instead.

But I also need to set the sessionAuthenticationStrategy.  Sadly, this is also null at this time.  I've noticed the 'standard' filters all use a 'Configurer' to set them up, and apparently by this time, all the beans are correctly defined.  But I haven't figured out how to register my 'configurer' instead of my filter directly.

So.. how does one build a custom AuthenticationProcessingFilter with the required attributes defined within a java configuration adapter?

Comment: PS, I figured I set up the SessionFixationStrategy already via  SessionManagementConfigurer<HttpSecurity> sessionManagementConfigurer = http.sessionManagement().sessionFixation().newSession(), but that seems insufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I figured out how to setup a configurer for my custom filter.  HttpSecurity.apply() takes a configurer and you can invoke that during the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.configure(http) method.  Turns out trying to set up filters at that time is probably a bad idea.. at least filters that depend on other portions of the security infrastructure.

Inside your configurer, create and add a security filter using init(http) and configure(http).  By the time the configurers are invoked, many shared objects have been defined and inserted into http, things such as the AuthenticationManager and the SessionAuthenticationStrategy instances.

Comment: I realize it's been a while since you posted this, but I'm trying to something similar and I'm having difficulty figuring out how to "set up a configurer".  What class or interface did you use?  The built-in configurers are worthless because they all are defined with  `extends AbstractHttpConfigurer` which is "for internal use only" according to the docs.

Comment: If I remember correctly, you use a Configurer Adapter : for example WebMvcConfigurerAdapter